# Check if given series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

how can we find if given series is convergent

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n + (-1)^n)^\frac{1}{2}} 
$$

What I've tried to do:

$$
\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)^\frac{1}{2}(1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{2n})^\frac{1}{2}}
$$

then

$$ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)^\frac{1}{2}} * (1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{2n})^\frac{-1}{2}$$

then using Taylor series I got

$$ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)^\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{4n*(2n)^\frac{1}{2}} + o(\frac{1}{n^2})$$

$$ \frac{1}{4n*(2n)^\frac{1}{2}} + o(\frac{1}{n^2})$$ this "tail" converges abolutely hence we can say that convergence of main series same as convergence of $$\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)^\frac{1}{2}}$$

and this value converges due to Alternating series test, so main series (1) converges.
Now I need to check whether it converges absolutely or conditionally.
Using
$$ (2) \frac{|(-1)^n|}{|(2n)^\frac{1}{2}|} \ge \frac{1}{|(2n)^\frac{1}{2}|} (3) $$
now using divergence of (3) series and Direct comparison test we get that (2) series diverges, so our main series (1) converges conditionally.

The answer is: (1) converges conditionally. Are my solution & answer correct?

Comment: Actually you can apply the Leibniz alternating test directly as $2n+(-1)^n\le 2(n+1)+(-1)^{n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

It is worth looking at the partial sums.  It should then be immediately obvious that the sum from $n=2$ to $n=k$ is

- $0$ when $k$ is odd, since each pair of terms cancel each other out
- $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}$ when $k$ is even, since you are left with the $n=k$ term, which decreases towards $0$

so the partial sums converge to $0$ as $k$ increases.

The partial sums of the  absolute values from $n=2$ to $n=k$ are greater than $\int_2^{k+1} \frac{1}{2x+1}\,dx = \sqrt{2k+3}-\sqrt{5}$, which  increases without bound, so the original expression has conditional convergence rather than absolute convergence.